# Select in channel

Tags: go

The following is one example code for select. I don't understand why the second select doesn't execute the first case? The output seems to be:

```
messages := make(chan string)
signals := make(chan bool)

// Here's a non-blocking receive. If a value is
// available on `messages` then `select` will take
// the `<-messages` `case` with that value. If not
// it will immediately take the `default` case.
select {
case msg := <-messages:
    fmt.Println("received message", msg)
default:
    fmt.Println("no message received")
}

// A non-blocking send works similarly.
msg := "hi"
select {
case messages <- msg:
    fmt.Println("sent message", msg)
default:
    fmt.Println("no message sent")
}

// We can use multiple `case`s above the `default`
// clause to implement a multi-way non-blocking
// select. Here we attempt non-blocking receives
// on both `messages` and `signals`.
select {
case msg := <-messages:
    fmt.Println("received message", msg)
case sig := <-signals:
    fmt.Println("received signal", sig)
default:
    fmt.Println("no activity")
}
```

After I run the code, the output:

```
no message received
no message sent
no activity
```

Updated: I know why the second select goes to default now. What about the third one?

Answer (score 3):

`messages` is unbuffered, and no other Go routine is blocked waiting for something to be received. Since the send operation will block, the `default` case is executed.

Compare this to the behaviour of a [buffered channel](https://play.golang.org/p/YM7iOtPsew) or [when another Go routine is blocked reading on the channel](https://play.golang.org/p/mn0YfQpV8j).

From the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Select_statements):

> 2. If one or more of the communications can proceed, a single one that can proceed is chosen via a uniform pseudo-random selection. Otherwise, if there is a default case, that case is chosen.

Comment: Thanks, what about the next one then? We already push the msg to messages. The first case should be executed, why still the default one?

Comment: You haven't sent `msg` to `messages`. That send doesn't execute because it would block; that's why the text printed from that case is "no message sent".